# I can't specify the location of Subversion repository in Netbeans

Tags: svn, netbeans, tortoisesvn, environment-variables

In Tools>Options>Miscellaneous>Versioning>Subversion, I can't type the Repository URL under "Manage Connection Settings..." It just shows me a blank drop-down menu when I click on the input field.
Also, if I select "SvnKit" under "Preferred client", it doesn't configure it this way, I click OK but when I come back to the options menu, "CLI" is marked and I can't use this because it's deprecated, according to the Netbeans website ( http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSubversionClients ).
When I try to use the checkout, I get:

```
NetBeans Subversion support required a Subversion client!
Install Subversion Commandline Client

1. Download and Install Subversion 1.5 or later (http://collabnet.net/netbeans).
2. Add it to PATH.
Test the installation by running 'svn --version' from a command line
3. Restart the IDE
```

I've specified C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin under my PATH environment variable but I still get

```
 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm running Tortoise 1.8.3 on Win 8 x64 Netbeans 7.3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN is a GUI and Windows-Integrated svn client. It doesn't provide the svn.exe and svn tools Netbeans needs. (See the reference to -commandline- in the error message.) [Collabnet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion) or cygwin can provide the proper tools for Netbeans.

Per comments

Here is my path, what you need bolded, Other SCMs emphasized:

C:\Users\jpotkanski>path
PATH=**C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client**;C:\Windows\system32;C:\W
indows;C:\Windows\system32\wbem;C:\Program Files\RSA SecurID Token Common;C:\Pro
gram Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Program Fi
les (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Microsoft Online Services;C:\Windows\SYS
TEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\SERVICES\IPT;C:\PROGRA
M FILES\THINKPAD\BLUETOOTH SOFTWARE;C:\PROGRAM FILES\THINKPAD\BLUETOOTH SOFTWARE
\SYSWOW64;;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Co
mmon7\IDE;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;c:\Program
Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL S
erver\100\DTS\Binn;*C:\Program Files\Mercurial*;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Pla
tform Installer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Inte
l\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\
Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;
C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCom
mon\;*C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin*;C:\Ruby193\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi
\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\

Comment: Thanks but still, now I've got a CLI and an svn.exe. NB still prompts the same message. Any further step I should take after installing collab.net?

Comment: Reboot? Svn should be in your path, else fix your svn directory in netbeans.

Comment: "I've specified C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin under my PATH environment variable"

Comment: That's incorrect, you need to point the path to where svn.exe is located.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the location surrounded with quotes:

"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin" not C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin

Answer (score 0):

This is due to incorrect selection of options during the installation of SVN.

Below is the solution:
While installing, make sure to change the command line client tools from "**Entire feature will be unavailable**" to "**Will be installed on local hard drive**".